# Why JUnit test methods need to be void?

Tags: java, junit

I've read in lot of places that test methods should/must be `void`, but no one says what is the reason for this.

I found in [MethodValidator](http://www.srcrr.com/java/junit/4.8.2/reference/org/junit/internal/runners/MethodValidator.html) the following check without comments/javadocs.

```
    if (each.getReturnType() != Void.TYPE) {
        errors.add(new Exception("Method " + each.getName()
                + " should be void"));
    }
```

So why it should be `void`?

Comment: Why would a unit test be anything other than void? Returning values from a unit tests method makes no sense, so if a unit tests method returns a value, it is probably not a correct unit test or not intended as a unit test.

Comment: Because nobody is going to look at their return values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask you the reverse question : why JUnit test methods would need to be not `void` ?
No reason : because a test method is not designed to return a result that will be exploited by a client class.
The goal of an unit test is validating some assertions. A test runner invokes the test methods and and this is the runner that interprets any assertion failure or any exception thrown during the test execution to produce the test result.

We could wonder why tests don't return the assertion result.
But it would be a bad idea as it would be very cumbersome to write unit tests :

```
@Test
public AssertionResult foo(){
   Bar actualBar = foo.doThat(...);
   if (actualBar == null){
       return AssertionResult.fail("actualBar == null");
   }
}
```

Write something like that is really readable and straight :

```
@Test
public void foo(){
   Bar actualBar = foo.doThat(...);
   Assert.assertNotNull(actualBar);
}
```

We could also wonder why test methods cannot be invoked by other test methods such as :

```
@Test
public int foo(){
   Bar actualBar = foo.doThat(...);
   //...
   return intValue;
}

@Test
public void fooWithComputedInt(){
   Bar actualBar = foo.doThat(foo());
   //...
}
```

But this also would be not a good idea as this would couple the tests execution while unit tests execution has to be isolated from others. And it also would make the tests be executed multiple times and unit tests have to be executed as fast as possible.

So really no value to make a test method return other thing than `void`.

Comment: im sure you know what your saying but i dont have a clue 

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a design choice. JUnit does not know about your code, so it could not do anything if your method would return something.

So either it should discard a return value, or require you to use "void" methods. The authors chose the latter option - you could argue that this slightly better because it's not confusing the reader.

Note that non-@Test methods are free to do whatever they want - they don't have this limitation.

Comment: For what reason JUnit can't do anything if my method returns something? How it blocks JUnit?

Comment: @ArtemMalchenko It doesn't block it in any way. JUnit calls your `@Test` methods - there is simply no convention what it should do with the value if your method returned one. Any checks for success/failure are done using assertions (i.e. throwables) - you could say this is "the only result JUnit cares about" (eventhough it's not really a "return").